# boost::spirit::xml::encode for wide string

Tags: c++, xml, boost, encoding, wstring

I'm currently using `boost::spirit::xml::encode` function to encode a given `std::string` to xml. But this function doesn't work for `std::wstring`.

Is there any equivalent for this that works for wide strings as well?

Comment: What is the function? documented?

Comment: kinda. look here: http://www.tena-sda.org/doc/5.2.1/boost/d3/df1/namespaceboost_1_1spirit_1_1xml.html

Comment: It seems Boost.Spirit.Classic's function. If you use Boost.Spirit V2 later, You shouldn't use Classic. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/what_s_new/spirit_1_x.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for Wide strings since all the XML-important wide characters map to the single byte ones.